# Rails: How can I test for the presence of &#161; in mailer text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, rspec-rails

I'm trying to rewrite an rspec mailer test and I cannot figure out how to account for the special character  ¡ in this text:

```
<p>
  You have been added to the <%= @user.organization.name %> organization in &#161;Generic!
</p>
```

Here's a snippet of the failing test:

```
 it 'renders the body' do
      puts @user.email
      body = mail.body.encoded
      #The following line is obviously incorrect, just an idea of what I'm trying to achieve
      body.should match "You have been added to the #{@user.organization.name} in ¡Generic!"
 end
```

I'm still super new to everything above basic rspec, and could really use some guidance on how to test for the presence of the inverted exclamation point .

Thanks!!!

**UPDATE**

I've was able to get the correct text displayed in the console error, but it still doesn't match. Here's how I did it:

```
it 'renders the body' do
  
  body = mail.body.encoded
  body.should match 'Hello test@email.com,'
  body.should match "You have been added to the #{@user.organization.name} organization in \u{00A1}Generic!"
```

and here's the new error:

```
Failures:

  1) UserInviteMailer send_invite renders the body
     Failure/Error: body.should match "You have been added to the #{@user.organization.name} organization in \u{00A1}Generic!"

       expected "\r\n----==_mimepart_6283bec023f29_1c0610c20237b9\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nC...ing! \r\n</p>\r\n\r\n  </body>\r\n</html>\r\n\r\n----==_mimepart_6283bec023f29_1c0610c20237b9--\r\n" to match "You have been added to the Generic organization in ¡Generic!"
       Diff:
       @@ -1,62 +1,123 @@
       -You have been added to the Generic organization in ¡Generic!
       +
       +----==_mimepart_6283bec023f29_1c0610c20237b9
       +Content-Type: text/plain;
       + charset=UTF-8
       +Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
       +
       +Hello test@email.com,=0D
       +=0D
       +You have been added to the Generic organization in =C2=A1Generic!=0D
       +=0D
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you indeed only want to check if the `¡` is in the body, you could write it (the last line) up like this:

```rb
expect(body.match?(/¡/)).to eq true
```

So just a regexp that matches the special character you mentioned, and returns true if it is found, then use that as the condition for the test matcher.

Comment: I tried this and still got a failure, but I appreciate your time!!